# "OR"operator won;t work in this switch-case

Tags: javascript

In below try block we have a switch-case but when the `channeling` is `phone_pe` it goes into the `phonePeScheduler` func. but whenever i pass channeling as `phonepe` it is going into the default block. How can we modify the first case I want both the string.

```
try {
        const channeling =
            body?.data?.channel ||
            body?.data_link?.channel;
        switch (channeling) {
            case "phone_pe" || "phonepe":
                await phonePeScheduler(body, reqId);
                break;
            case "Gpay":
                await gpayScheduler(body);
                break;
            case "cash":
            default:
                await paymentHandling(body);
        }
```

I tried doing multiple things but they didnt worked.

Answer (score 2):

That's not the correct syntax. You cannot use || operator directly in case but you can use multiple case values without using a break between them, so your code becomes:

```
try {
    const channeling =
        body?.data?.channel ||
        body?.data_link?.channel;
    switch (channeling) {
        case "phone_pe":
        case "phonepe":
            await phonePeScheduler(body, reqId);
            break;
        case "Gpay":
            await gpayScheduler(body);
            break;
        case "cash":
        default:
            await paymentHandling(body);
    }
```

Comment: If "phone_pe" then go to "phonepe" case. Is as simple as that. As you can see, the "phone_pe" case hase no break meaning it will execute the next line of code when your value match the case, resulting in evaluating the next case, which may or may not match, and the switch case just works as you'd expect.

Comment: Oh he deleted the comment asking for explanation... sad.

Comment: i know how it works. but the explanation would help in the answer.